Grover's algorithm: Build the uniform quantum state over all $n$-bit strings
I am visualising the set $A_1$ as given in the IBM presentation found here: Grover's algorithm. In the presentation, this set is defined by the following expression:
$$A_1 = \{ x \in \Sigma^n: f(x) = 1\}\,,$$
and ${\left|A_1\right> }$ = $\frac{1}{\sqrt{|A_1|}} \sum_{x \in A_1} {|x\rangle }$, where ${\left|A_1\right> }$ denotes the quantum state vector that is uniform over the elements of $A_1$.
For example, I defined the following boolean formula: $f(x_0x_1x_2) = x_0x_1\land x_0x_2\land x_1x_2$. The set $A_1$, which corresponds to the set of $f(x) = 1$ is given by:
$A_1$ = $\{011,101,110,111\}$ because $f(011) = 1$, etc. and $|A_1| = 4\,.$
The superposition of each element of the set is given by (using a Hadamard gate for each qubit line):
$$\left|{011}\right> \mapsto \left|{+ - -}\right>\,, $$
$$\left|{101}\right> \mapsto \left|{- + -}\right>\,, $$
$$\left|{110}\right> \mapsto \left|{- - +}\right>\,, $$
$$\left|{111}\right> \mapsto \left|{- - -}\right>\,. $$
because $H\left|{0}\right> = |+\rangle$ and $H\left|{1}\right> = |-\rangle$
Therefore, the vector $\left|{A_1}\right>$ is given by the following sum of the superposition of qubits:
$${\left|A_1\right> } = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4}} \bigg(\left|{+ - -}\right> + \left|{- + -}\right> +\left|{- - +}\right> + \left|{- - -}\right> \bigg)\,. $$
As per the description, $\left|{A_1}\right>$ is a vector, so I need to add these four qubits and obtain a single one.
My question is how to add these four qubits and obtain a single one.

In the expression:
$$ |A_1\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{|A_1|}} \sum_{x \in A_1} {|x\rangle }, $$
what $x \in A_1$ means is that you should replace every value of $x$ that belongs to the set $A_1$ inside the ket $|x\rangle$. Therefore, for $A_1 = \{011,101,110,111\}$, you have:
$$ |A_1\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4}} \left(|011\rangle + |101\rangle + |110\rangle + |111\rangle \right). $$
In column-vector representation, this is equal to a single vector of the form:
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
|A_1\rangle &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{4}} \left(\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} +\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \right)
\\
\\
|A_1\rangle &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{4}} \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{aligned}
$$
